# Perform calculation only if both cells are not blank with arrayformula?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

i am having difficult understanding what went wrong with my logic in google sheet.

Imagine if i have two columns with dates (column A and G). And i have an empty column to perform the calculation of date difference (A and G), and includes the start/end date using array formula.

I written the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)), NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G))),DAYS(A2:A,G2:G)+1))
```

but it return FALSE to me on the first row even both cell A and G has a date, and the array formula didn't get to fill out for the subsequent rows.

If I changed to the following using OR operator:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(OR(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)), NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G))),DAYS(A2:A,G2:G)+1))
```

It does work but not what i wish it to behave. If either column is filled, it produce -44468 or 44468; and if neither column is filled, it produce 1.

How can i fix my code above such that if both cell A and G is not blank, then only perform the calculation of the date difference, else return as NULL or blank?

And i wish to use arrayformula so that i don't have to copy the formula into every single rows in future.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with excel?

Comment: well, i thought the issue is with logic part, so somewhat excel would be similar. Are you able to shed some light on this?

Comment: Arrayformula doesn't work with and/or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, i've learnt something new - Boolean algebra to handle array formula using `IF`, `AND` and `OR` logical function.

I managed to have another solution producing the correct results.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A<>"")*(G2:G<>""), DAYS(A2:A,G2:G)+1,""))`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use AND/OR with ARRAYFORMULA

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A) + ISBLANK(G2:G) > 0,,DAYS(A2:A,G2:G)+1))
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike Steelson. This is indeed working.

Answer (score 1):

`AND` & `OR` operations are not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`

instead of `AND` use `*`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)))*(NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G))), DAYS(A2:A, G2:G)+1), )
```

instead of `OR` use `+`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)))+(NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G))), DAYS(A2:A, G2:G)+1), )
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I've tested your formula but it returns as ERROR, managed to tweak it as per below in order to work

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A))*NOT(ISBLANK(G2:G)), DAYS(A2:A, G2:G)+1,""))`

But the concept is there. I just learned that this is called Boolean Algebra.

Comment: @Ryan fixed. answer updated. btw `NOT(ISBLANK(` is not the same as `<>`