# Using IF, AND/OR (many condition) with Array formula in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Could someone help me?

I'd like to use the Array formula with AND/OR as follows but it doesn't work

=ArrayFormula(if(AND(AG2:AG="Yes",AI2:AI<>""),"Ok","Blank"))

It similar to OR

How can I use this in case I need to put more than 2 conditions in the AND/OR when using the Array formula?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform calculation only if both cells are not blank with arrayformula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70133244/perform-calculation-only-if-both-cells-are-not-blank-with-arrayformula)

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your suggestion, in my question the condition is the text which  is not number for calculating I have gone through the 3 answers but can not work

Comment: Have you tried my answer here after ? If necessary, give a link to your spreadsheet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayFormula and "AND" Formula in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710792/arrayformula-and-and-formula-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 12):

Do not use AND/OR with ARRAYFORMULA, use `+` instead of OR and `*` instead of AND with IF

Try

```
=ArrayFormula(if((AG2:AG="Yes")*(AI2:AI<>""),"Ok","Blank"))
```

You can add other conditions if you respect the syntax with `+` or `*`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mike it's wonderful guidance, thanks so much. It's worked perfectly

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Already voted for your answer. I'm a newbie in this forum, this is my first question, hope will get your help with the next questions. Haha